# How to set new filename for python logger which is file-configured?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I has the python logger which is configured by file.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, errorHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, errorHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('%(filename)s',)

[handler_errorHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('error.log',)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

So, I call the configuration file like this:
`logging.config.fileConfig('logging.cfg', defaults={'filename': 'may2020.log'})`
But I want to change filename monthly. For example, now filename is set to `may2020.log`, and it the beginning of the next month I want to rename it as `june2020.log`. How can I dynamically change the filename without restarting the application?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but for anyone interested:

There is a handler for this exact purpose:
[logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [edit] to add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be _helpful_, but avoid making it _necessary_ to click on them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.cfg', defaults={'filename': f'{now.strftime("%B").lower()}{now.year}.log'})
```

This will work on Python 3.6+

Comment: How can I dynamically change it? It I call this function one more time, logger stops working!